# Where is the best place load a YAML application config file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, app-config, actionmailer, environment

I have setup my application configuration for my rails 3.1 application as described [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file) by Ryan Bates.

Problem is I want to use the config in my environment file for username/password for ActionMailer, but Ryan suggests loading the config from an initializer, and they seem to get included after environment.rb. Where is the best place to load the configuration file so it can be accessed by the whole rails application?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that case, this code should go in as a pre-initializer. As of Rails 3, all pre-initialization code needs to go near the top of application.rb, just before the line `require 'rails/all'`

**application.rb:**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)  

# load app_config.yml  
require 'yaml'  
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../app_config.yml', __FILE__)))  

require 'rails/all'
```

Comment: How do you select the right environment? shouldn't you add [Rails.env] at the end (but you can't before `'rails/all'`)